# Show that $(n − 1) + (n − 2) + · · · + (n − (n − 1)) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} n − 1 − 2 − 3 − · · · − (n − 1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This equivalence is showing up in a derivation for the variance of the mean of a sampling distribution:

$(n − 1) + (n − 2) + · · · + (n − (n − 1)) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} n − 1 − 2 − 3 − · · · − (n − 1)$

I have not been able to understand how this is true. For instance just choosing $n = 3$ evaluates to different values:

$\begin{align}
(3-1)+(3-(3-1)) &= \sum_{i=1}^{3}3-1-(3-1) \\
2+1&=3(3-1-2) \\
3&\neq0
\end{align}$

I think there is something obvious that I am not seeing, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: The correct equation should be $$LHS= \sum_{i=1}^ {n-1} n-i$$

Comment: @wyattan dont forget to accept some answer by click on gray "check button" on its left side (only for one answer), If you want you can also add +10 point to author by clicking on upper gray trinagle (you can do it for many answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the upper bound (shown in blue) and interpret that as
$$
(\color{red}{n} − 1) + (\color{red}{n} − 2) + \dots + (\color{red}{n} − (n − 1)) = 
\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{\color{blue}{n-1}} n \biggr) − 1 − 2 − 3 − \dots − (n − 1)
$$
which is essentially obvious: pull all $n$ terms (marked red) in the left-hand side at the beginning.

For instance, if $n=4$, the left-hand side is
$$
3+2+1=6
$$
while the right hand side is
$$
3\cdot4-1-2-3=6
$$

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not make mistake then left side:
$$\begin{align}(n − 1) + (n − 2) + · · · + (n − (n − 1)) &= (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 \\
 &= 1 + 2 + ... + (n-2) + (n-1) = n(n-1)/2 \\
&= (n^2 -n)/2\end{align}$$

and right side:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{n} n − 1 − 2 − 3 − · · · − (n − 1) &=n( n − 1 − 2 − 3 − · · · − (n − 1) )\\
&= n(n -  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i) = n(n-n(n-1)/2)\\
&=(3n^2 - n^3)/2\end{align}$$

left $\neq$ right